# AppleScript scrape iOS simulator

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator, applescript

I want to scrape the screen of the iOS Simulator on OSX. I want to be able to take the text of the UI screen that I load up in iOS Simulator and output it to a text file where I can further manipulate the text. Is this possible? have any of you tried something similar before?  I would like to do this in AppleScript.

The reason for the AppleScript choice is my team have a lot of their automation tasks scripted in AppleScript already and I should be able to take advantage of this to recycle some of it. That and the fact that I don’t have any Objective-C experience which looks a lot different to OO languages I have seen and I do not have the time to learn. This tool needs to be up and running in the next 2 weeks.

So is this possible?
Any help\pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible in 2 weeks, I have not seen anything for this, so you will have to develop something yourself, which will take way more than 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy job if you use gui scripting in applescript. The difficult part is finding the references to the ui elements... but it's not difficult at all if you use a tool like [UI Browser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/). I don't run the iOS simulator, but you can get things from the front window of any application using gui scripting, so I don't think a simulator window is any different.

For example, I'm looking at this safari window. Can I get some text from this window? Sure... let's say I want to get the url text using gui scripting. I could use this...

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
delay 0.2

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        set textfieldReference to text field 1 of splitter group 1 of group 3 of tool bar 1 of window 1
        set urlText to value of textfieldReference
    end tell
end tell
```

There's some tricky things about gui scripting but if you use it properly then it shouldn't be a problem. Note that this code to scrape this text from the safari window took all of 2 minutes to write. The most difficult part was getting the textfieldReference.

NOTE: for gui scripting to work you have to enable "Enable access for assistive devices" in the Universal Access preference pane.

The next part is manipulating the text which you can do easily right in applescript using text item delimiters and other applescript tools. So overall the job seems simple to me and the required skills aren't too much.

Comment: I looked at the UIBrowser tool and it gives me more info than Accessibility Inspector. I have question about the AppleScript, It compiles but does not run for me i get "error "System Events got an error: Can’t get group 3 of tool bar 1 of window 1 of process \"Safari\". Invalid index." number -1719 from group 3 of tool bar 1 of window 1 of process "Safari" Any idea whats wrong? It be great to see it working & the content s scraped from the screen myself with what seems to be very little code indeed.

Comment: I got that working on OSX changing "group 3" to "group 2". I also see how your lifting the text of safari.I tried that with the iOS Simulator and it works exactly the same. Delighted! I am now wondering how i would lift all of the text of the screen if there were different buttons, text, tabs etc.. No screen will consist of the same items and i don't want to have to hardcode each individual screen with all the different UI elements. I want the script to be able to detect the different items in the UI and print them all out.

Comment: You have to find a programmatic way to get all of the ui elements of the window. You get that in a list. Then you loop through the list, check the class of the element, and when you find a text field or other text containing element then you gets its value. I've seen this type of code before so you'll have to google for it.